# How to set different images in grid view?

Tags: android, gridview

I want to display different images using gridview in android?
Xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >

<GridView android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
 android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Android[Java Code]:

```
public class Backgroundimage extends Activity
     {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
     gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
          }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
                  {
    private Context mContext;
    public ImageAdapter(Context c)
           {
               mContext = c;
          }

      public int getCount()
        {
        return mThumbIds.length;
        }

    public Object getItem(int position)
          { 
       return null;
            }

    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
    return 0;
     }
    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
    ImageView imageView;
                                                    if (convertView == null)
    {
     imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setPadding(6, 6, 6, 6);
    }
    else
    {
    imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
     }
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
      return imageView;
                                    }
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,
            R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4,
                       };
    }   


}
```

But the image1 is appear in all postion like this image is appear in grid view in row and column.but other images are not displayed.How to rectify this problem?

Comment: where is your code ...what you have tried..

Comment: how to create the onclick function when i click the each images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple brother....

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
ImageView imageView;
                                                if (convertView == null)
{
 imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
imageView.setPadding(6, 6, 6, 6);
}
else
{
imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
 }
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);         
  return imageView;
```

}

in above code change

```
 imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
```

to

```
 imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
```

and make sure add number of element in mThumbs array that you want child of Gridview

**Second doubt**
 after this line
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
use this

```
gritview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View imageview, int pos,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: did you solve it?if yes then accept answer from which you got help

Comment: How to create onclick function when i click each images

Comment: in oncreate of activity your to set  setonItemClickListener to grid view object.By which you will get position of item in grid

Comment: Error :The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (new OnItemClickListener(){})

Comment: OnItemClickListener cannot be resolved to a type BookShelf.java

Comment: i have edited after checking it .its working for me.try again please

Comment: yes. actually i didnt implement the onitemclicklistner.now fine.thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your code as below:- (Changes in marked with `/* */`)

```
public class Backgroundimage extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

     GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
     gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
   }

 public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount(){
      return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position){ 
       return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position){
       return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

     ImageView imageView;
     if (convertView == null){
      imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
      imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
      imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
      imageView.setPadding(6, 6, 6, 6);
    }else{
     imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    /* Change Here in your code  */
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

   return imageView;
}

private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,
            R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4};
    } 
}
```

Comment: How to create the onclick function when  i click each images?is there any possiblites

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
```

add this instead of above

```
 imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
```

Comment: "How to reduce the size of image1,image2 image 3,image 4 in the grid view

Comment: imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85)); this is the line to set width and height..